# Redirect application to use another assemlby with different name

Tags: c#, .net, redirect, binding

My .Net C# appliation is referencing a strong named dll,and my requiremnet is to redirect the application to use another dll with a different name ( version and key are same for both dlls), how can i achive this without recompiling the application.

Comment: do they derive from the same interface?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the offical doc on this: [Redirecting Assembly Versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28VS.71%29.aspx) (check out the "Specifying Assembly Binding in Configuration Files" section, this is the most easy to do)

Comment: Yeah, but that means redirecting ALL access to that library, not just the application. Still is also a good approach if you own both and you have no other applications that need to use the later (and of course assuming you have the private key). +1

Comment: @Jorge - If you change the myapp.exe.config (or create one if there isn't any) aside myapp.exe, it will redirect only this application.

Answer (score 0):

[Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) might be a solution.

At the point you know what dll you want to use pull in the dll by reflection.

If both dlls derive from the same interface then the rest of the code can be very generic no matter the dll you use.

Answer (score 0):

You can't as far as i know. That's the beauty of it, strong named assemblies are produced with a signature, precisely to avoid what you're trying to do.

After all it wouldn't have much security if you could just substitute a DLL from another one and having the new DLL methods do whatever you want under the original caller context would it?